# Set Virtual Path to ASP NET Core MVC Application behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nginx, asp.net-core

I have an ASP NET Core application running inside a docker container and I'm trying to access this application using a NGINX Reverse Proxy that I built inside another docker container.

When I try to access the MVC Application using the virtual path that I configured on Nginx .conf files, like this: "http://localhost:1000/mvcapp/", all the css, js and othrr static files that uses relative paths are not found, because mvc doesnt handle the virtual path to configure correctly the path for those files.

my url: http://localhost:1000/mvc

path that mvc builts: href="/css/bootstrap.css"

the correct way that mvc should built: href="mvc/css/bootstrap"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like your reverse proxy works in a way that maps `/mvcapp` to `/` as below:

```
location /mvcapp {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:6009/;    # assume you expose the 6009 port
    ...
}
```

If that's the case, that's because the proxy cuts off the `/mvcapp` prefix. And your MVC app doesn't realize the virtual app path is `/mvcapp`. To fix that, add a middleware to set the `PathBase` explicitly:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // add this middleware as the first one
    app.Use((context, next)=> {
        context.Request.PathBase = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_APPL_PATH");
        return next();
    });          
    //  ... other middlewares
}
```

And pass the `ASPNETCORE_APPL_PATH` environment when starting the docker. For example, you can pass the environment in the command:

```
## assume you want to map the port 6009 to 80, 
##     and the image name is nginxtocore
docker run -p 6009:80 -e ASPNETCORE_APPL_PATH='/mvcapp'  nginxtocore
```